# .NET MAUI Getting Error When Transfering Data Between Pages

Tags: c#, pdf, maui

I'm a newbie in .NET MAUI platform and I have problem.

When I try to pass data between pages of my app it gives this error: `System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for: PdfViewer?pdfName=EN 10305-2 Arg_ParamName_Name'`

In my app, I want to open PDF files according to user's selection. For example, when user clicked on first button, the app will open first PDF file. When user did the same thing for the second button, the will open second PDF file. Right now, everything works execpt this one. Normally, without passing data, the app passes to the page that I want but when I try to do it with transferring data, it gives me this error. I'm sharing the codes of pages below:

(I named my main page as "AnaSayfa")

AnaSayfa.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Class="borkatalogYeni.AnaSayfa"
         Title="Ana Sayfa"
         BackgroundColor="LightGray">

<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto">
    <Entry Grid.Row="0" Placeholder="Ara" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"></Entry>
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyCollectionView" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding UserItems}" SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" VerticalItemSpacing="1"></GridItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" 
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

AnaSayfa.xaml.cs

```
namespace borkatalogYeni;

public partial class AnaSayfa : ContentPage
{
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<Item> Items;
AnaSayfaViewModel anaSayfaViewModel;

public AnaSayfa()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = anaSayfaViewModel = new AnaSayfaViewModel();
}

void Entry_TextChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
    {
        MyCollectionView.ItemsSource = anaSayfaViewModel.UserItems;
    }
    else 
    {
        MyCollectionView.ItemsSource = anaSayfaViewModel.UserItems.Where(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));
    }
}
}
```

AnaSayfaViewModel.cs (The ViewModel of my Main Page)

```
namespace borkatalogYeni
{
public class AnaSayfaViewModel : BindableObject
{
    public class UserItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private UserItem selectedListItem;
    public UserItem SelectedListItem
    {
        get { return selectedListItem; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedListItem != value) 
            {
                selectedListItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedListItem");

                if (selectedListItem != null) 
                {
                    PerformNavigation(selectedListItem.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async void PerformNavigation(string GetName)
    {
        //I'm getting the error in here
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(PdfViewer)}?pdfName={GetName}");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UserItem> userItems;
    public ObservableCollection<UserItem> UserItems
    {
        get 
        {
            return userItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (userItems != value) 
            {
                userItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserItems");
            }
        }
    }

    public AnaSayfaViewModel() 
    {
        UserItems = new ObservableCollection<UserItem>
        {
            new UserItem{Name = "EN 10305-2"},
            new UserItem{Name = "EN 10305-3"},
            new UserItem{Name = "EN 10305-5"}
        };
    }
}
}
```

PdfViewer.xaml (I'm opening PDF files in this page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Class="borkatalogYeni.PdfViewer"
         Title="PdfViewer">

<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="webViewPdf"
             Grid.Row="1"
             HorizontalOptions="Fill"
             VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
</Grid>
```

PdfViewer.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PdfViewer : ContentPage
{
public PdfViewer(PdfViewerViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
    
    //In here, I wanted to open PDF files with the data that I tried to bring from main page
    //string pdfName = "";
    //webViewPdf.Source = pdfName + ".pdf";
    //this.Title = pdfName;
}
}
```

PdfViewerViewModel.cs (View model of PdfViewer page)

```
namespace borkatalogYeni
{
//After integrated view model, I tried to pass data to here but unfortunately I'm failed
[QueryProperty("pdfName", "pdfName")]
public partial class PdfViewerViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string pdfName;
}
}
```

Comment: try removing the spaces from the names, or urlencoding them

Comment: @Jason I removed the spaces from the names, I did it like EN10305-2 but it gave me same error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please register route for your page. You can register route in file `AppShell.xaml.cs`

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this funciton.
You can refer to the following code:

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell 
{
    public Dictionary<string, Type> Routes { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public AppShell()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        Routes.Add("pdfviewer", typeof(PdfViewer));


        foreach (var item in Routes)
        {
            Routing.RegisterRoute(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**PfViewer.xaml.cs**

```
[QueryProperty("pdfName", "pdfName")] 
public partial class PdfViewer : ContentPage
{
    public string pdfName
    {
        set
        {
            LoadData(value);
        }
    }

    private void LoadData(string value)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---> received data is: "+value);

        try
        {
            BindingContext =  new PdfViewerViewModel(value);

            this.Title = value;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to load data.");
        }
    }

    public PdfViewer()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

      //  BindingContext = vm;

        //In here, I wanted to open PDF files with the data that I tried to bring from main page
        //string pdfName = "";
        //webViewPdf.Source = pdfName + ".pdf";
        //this.Title = pdfName;
    }
}
```

**PdfViewerViewModel.cs**

```
public partial class PdfViewerViewModel: ObservableObject 
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string pdfName;

    public PdfViewerViewModel(string name) { 
       this.pdfName = name;
    }
}
```

In `AnaSayfaViewModel.cs`,modify method `PerformNavigation` as follows:

```
    private async void PerformNavigation(string GetName) 
    {

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"pdfviewer?pdfName={GetName}");

    }
```